# Application built with .NET 3.5 running on machine with only .NET 4.0. How does supportedRuntime element work?

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-3.5

We have an application that was built using .NET 3.5. There is a situation where it will run on a machine which only has .NET 4.0 installed.

If in the application configuration file the `<supportedRuntime>` element is not defined, or is defined as follows

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

will the application crash on start up since .NET 3.5 and CLR v2.0.50727 are not present?

Note I understand that .NET 4.0 APIs are supposed to be compatible with .NET 3.5 ones and that a .NET 3.5 application *should* run in .NET 4.0. That is not the question. I am specifically asking about the `<supportedRuntime>` behavior.

Comment: Yes it will crash.  You'll need to add another one with `version="v4.0"` to make it run on .NET 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Hans Passant's comment as it seems a suitable answer.

The application will crash. To run on .NET 4.0 you need to add another supportedRuntime attribute with version="4.0".